# Java: How to set value when button is clicked?

Tags: java, button, actionlistener

I need to program a button which sets value when it's clicked. How to write an actionPerformed method to work so?

```
int a = 0;

void setValue(){
  a = 5;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  /*when*/ e.getActionCommand() /*call setValue()*/
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so show the code you used to try and accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  JButton button = new JButton(" >> JavaProgrammingForums.com <<");
        //Add action listener to button
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                a = 5 ;
                System.out.println("You clicked the button");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got error in my asd class that "asd is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener"

Comment: put `@Override` ahead `actionPerformed` method.

Comment: @Zygimantas : see answer update and tell me is it solved or not ?

Comment: If your problem is solved then accept the answer so other people don't  visit your solved question.

Answer (score 0):

Make a button and then add ActionListener to it like this

```
private static JButton btn;
private statin int a;
btn = new JButton();
int a = 0;
btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    a = 15;
    }
}
```